# multiple keyword search using php mysql result related record

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID    CODE      STATE    CITY            AREA
1   SBIN0000952 ORISSA  JAIPUR          TOWN
2   SBIN0000953 ORISSA  KURAPUT         VILLAGE
3   SBIN0000954 DELHI   DELHI           TOWN
4   SBIN0000955 DELHI   NEW DELHI       VILLAGE
5   SBIN0000956 GOA     SOUTH GOA       VILLAGE
6   SBIN0000957 GOA     PANAJI          TOWN
7   SBIN0000958 KERLA   CHOCHIN         TOWN
8   SBIN0000959 KERLA   TRIVANDRAM      VILLAGE
9   SBIN0000960 ANDHRA  VIZAG           TOWN
10  SBIN0000961 ANDHRA  HYDERABAD       VILLAGE
```

above is my table and i want search a multiple keyword for example

kerla town then it should display the record

```
7   SBIN0000958 KERLA   CHOCHIN    TOWN
```

below my present code in php

```
include('dbConnect.inc.php');

//collect
if(!isset($_POST['search'])){
    header("Location:index.php");

} 
    $searchq = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['search']);
    $search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE STATE LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CITY LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CODE LIKE '%$searchq%' ";
    $search_query = mysql_query($search_sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0){
    $search_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
    }
```

to print

```
<?php if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0){
    do{ ?>

    <?php 

    $bank = $search_rs['BANK'];
    $ifsc = $search_rs['IFSC'];
    $branch= $search_rs['BRANCH'];
    $micr = $search_rs['MICR_CODE'];
    $address = $search_rs['ADDRESS'];
    $contact = $search_rs['CONTACT'];
    $city = $search_rs['CITY'];
    $district = $search_rs['DISTRICT'];
    $state = $search_rs['STATE'];
         ?>
         <table width="100%" border="2" bordercolor="#000" class="bdrcolor">


    <tbody>     
  <tr>
    <td width="15%"><?=$bank?></td> 
       <td width="15%"><?=$branch?></td>
       <td width="15%"><b>IFSC:</b><?=$ifsc?> <br /><b>MICR:</b><?=$micr?></td>
       <td width="20%"><?=$address?><br /> <b>City :</b><?=$city?> <br /> <b>District :</b><?=$district?> <br /> <b>State:</b> <?=$state?></td> 
       <td width="10%"><?=$contact?></td>
  </tr>
  <br />
  </tbody>
</table>



    <?php   }while ($search_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)); 

}else{
        echo "No Results";

        }


    ?>
```

its only giving the result of one keyword or no result

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated use PDO instead

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *one keyword*. Do you mean: 1 record, or 1 column, ... *keyword* usually refers to coding syntax like the keywords: `if`, `else`, `SELECT`, ...

Comment: see kerla and town  are two  keywords i want to display the result which match these keywords in the data base

Comment: see i have 2 kerla records in my data base when i search kerla i am getting all the recodes related to query that s fine , but when i specify kerla is my first keyword and town is my second keyword it should show only that particular records  which is related to kerla and town keywords not all the records of kerla, hope you understand my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate your result set, to see all records.

```
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result != NULL)
    {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
      {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
          // todo: use $key and $value
        }
      }
      mysql_free_result($result);
   }
```

**EDIT:**

In case you wondered, the call `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` really is the same thing as `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

**EDIT:**

If you want only to see the records that contain ALL keywords. Then you should change your SQL query, you need to use `AND` instead of `OR` in your sql query.

```
"SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE STATE LIKE '%$state%' AND CITY LIKE '%$city%' AND CODE LIKE '%$code%' ";
```

I guess not all keywords are used at all time. So you may want to build that query at runtime.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE 1=1";
if ($useCity) $query .= " AND city like '%{$city_keyword}%'";
if ($useState) $query .= " AND state like '%{$state_keyword}%'";
if ($useCode) $query .= " AND code like '%{$code_keyword}%'";
```

I didn't understand that very well from your question. Maybe you only want to include the keywords if they are specified ? (e.g. `$useCity = ($city_keyword != null);`)

**EDIT:**

From what I understood from your last post. You want the input to be split in words. And **each** word **must** match **at least 1** column. Meaning all words must be used to query. Then you could try this:

```
// split the input in words
$searchq = $_POST['search'];
$words = explode(" ", $searchq);
$wordCount = count($words);

// declare which columns should be searched
$columns = array("city", "town", "code", "area");
$columnCount = count($columns);

// start from a basic query, which we will expand later
$query = "SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE ";

// all words should be used
// that's why we are adding them with the 'AND' operator.
for($i=0;$i<$wordCount;$i++)
{
  $word = mysql_escape_string($words[$i]);
  if ($i > 0) $query .= " AND ";

  // build the condition
  $condition = " (";
  for($j=0;$j<$columnCount;$j++)
  {
    // but each word can match any column, doesn't matter which one.
    // that's why we are using the 'OR' operator here. 
    if ($j > 0) $condition .= " OR ";
    $column = $columns[$j];
    $condition .= " {$column} like '%{$word}%' ";
  }
  $condition .= ") ";
  $query .= $condition;
}
echo $query;
```

The trick here is that by building your sql at runtime, it will produce a totally different query depending on the number of words the user has used.

Comment: i am new to php i will explain i have records contain state district code ect.. now i have search form in that when i enter the any state name its displaying all the rows which is matching to state but when i give state and district name it should display only which is match state and district not all the recodes of state

Comment: @RaviShankar But it is not clear to me, how you can determine if the entered value is a state name or a district name ? If you want to filter strictly only records that contain all keywords, then you need to know exactly which type of keywords were entered by the user. Because if you filter the wrong column, you won't get any results at all.

Comment: i think you can help me in this my website is bankhints.com containing search box where i want to search bank name and city if i enter bank name and city it should show the result which match these keywords for example icici bank andhra pradesh then the records should be all icici bank which is in andhra pradesh it should not get all the icici bank records which also contain kerla, goa states

Comment: syntax error at column declaration  $columns = {"city", "town", "code", "area"};

Comment: GOT ERROR SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE ( BANK LIKE '% %' OR IFSC LIKE '% %' OR MICR_CODE LIKE '% %' OR BRANCH LIKE '% %' OR ADDRESS LIKE '% %' OR CITY LIKE '% %' OR DISTRICT LIKE '% %' OR STATE LIKE '% %' OR CONTACT LIKE '% %' )

Comment: its displaying the query not result how to display results please see below  SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE ( BANK like '%ICICI%' OR IFSC like '%ICICI%' OR MICR_CODE like '%ICICI%' OR BRANCH like '%ICICI%' OR ADDRESS like '%ICICI%' OR CITY like '%ICICI%' OR DISTRICT like '%ICICI%' OR STATE like '%ICICI%' OR CONTACT like '%ICICI%' ) AND ( BANK like '%BANK%' OR IFSC like '%BANK%' OR MICR_CODE like '%BANK%' OR BRANCH like '%BANK%' OR ADDRESS like '%BANK%' OR CITY like '%BANK%' OR DISTRICT like '%BANK%' OR STATE like '%BANK%' OR CONTACT like '%BANK%' )

Comment: bro thank you for your efforts i am getting the result i changed the code. but its not exactly i want can i have your email

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are only getting one row.  You need to replace the spaces in your string with commas and use something like this.

$search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE STATE in ($searchq) OR CITY in ($searchq) OR CODE in ($searchq)";

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the wrong direction. You are printing the table in the `if` condition. You should be doing the `printing` part in the `foreach` loop. You just have to define the `<table>` outside the `foreach` loop.

You have to use `foreach` loop

```
<table>
   <?php
       $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result)
        {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            {
               <tr>  /* (print the values ) */ </tr>
            }
          }
       }
 ?>
</table>
```

**NOTE:**

Please stop using `mysql*`, start using `mysqli*`  functions

Answer (score 0):

```
 include('dbConnect.inc.php');

 //collect
     if(!isset($_POST['search'])){
   header("Location:index.php");

 } 
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['search']);
$search_sql = "SELECT * FROM `bankifscin` WHERE STATE='%$searchq%' and`enter code here` CITY= '%$searchq%'";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0){
$search_rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
```

Comment: Your problem lies in your user interface. When the *search terms* (not *keywords*) 'Kerla' and 'Town' are passed to the query, the query should know exactly what to do with them.